# Can arbitrary function injection be performed on a PHP class?

Tags: php, security

I have the following piece of PHP code:

```
class test {
    function print_number() {
        echo 5;
    }
}
$myclass = new test();
$methodname = $_GET['f']";
$myclass->$methodname();
```

It outputs `5` when executed with `f` as `print_number`. Is this a secure thing to do? Can changing the value of `$methodname` to cause arbitrary code execution? Is it possible, for example, to force a `phpinfo()` or `eval()` by changing the value of `$methodname`? Or am I safe?